# Using ObjectIds for relationships? MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, relationships, objectid

I'm just putting my first steps in apps with MongoDB, and I'm not quite sure if what I'm doing is good practice or not.

I'm trying to do relationships between two collections. Let's say those will be `User` and `User_settings` collections. What I was going to do is adding field named `user_id`, that would contain obviously ID of document in `User` collection. And here come my concerns:

Should I use for it string format, or `ObjectId` format? I'm not sure it feels quite right to use `ObjectId` format. And that's because I experienced alot of problems while using this format in nodeJS apps. I had to convert `objectId` into `string`, in order to receive result I was looking for. Also, SailsJS is not allowing me to create new record with `ObjectId` fields. So my question is, can I use multiple `ObjectIds` in one record? I know I should do some googling, and I did. I'm just looking for 1-0 answer.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Well you can use any of the formats. You should just make sure to use the same format for the document's `_id`, and it's reference in another collection. Here's a comment that might help you put things to perspective: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/f-ljBdZOwPk/oQYZQxCAKN8J . And yes, you can use multiple `ObjectIds` in one record.

Comment: Not sure why you have 2 collections here, Usually user settings should be embeded in the user document, do not see any cases you have 2 collections.

Comment: AlexandruOlaru from the same reason, why I won't be storing user's posts in his profile collection, but I will create a new one to store those. That was just an example, to demonstrate my point of view - you got two collections, and you need to create a relationship between those.

@SiddharthAjmera thank you so much for your reply. That's kind of reply I was hoping to - clean short. :)